# monaco-editor integration with angular6 app

Tags: angular6, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I'm trying to integrate [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) into my angular lib in an Angular-6 app, I'm new at this and the official docs doesn't have any setup guide for the implementation. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **ngx-monaco-editor** NPM module

It provides support for various angular versions

In your case for Angular 6 you need to do

```
npm install ngx-monaco-editor@6.0.0 --save
```

then reference the module in your app.module

```
import { MonacoEditorModule } from 'ngx-monaco-editor';
...
imports: [
...
MonacoEditorModule.forRoot(),
...
```

and then in your html component you can use it like such:

```
<ngx-monaco-editor ... ></ngx-monaco-editor>
```

Read the readme here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-monaco-editor